# How to interpret the "rainy sunday afternoons" in this clause

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the meaning of the clause in the sentence below?
Is it expressing the author's love of "rainy sunday afternoons"?

> I want to be with someone who dreams of doing everything in life and **nothing on rainy sunday afternoons**.

Answer (score 1):

It means the author wants someone who will want to sit back and relax on days like Rainy Sunday Afternoons - usually considered a time to unwind, read a book, drink a cup of tea, or just generally laze around and enjoy the weather and free time of a Sunday.

The author is using that phrase as a contrast to "doing everything in life", which means the author wants someone with whom they can experience a lot of different things, and always be busy with one thing or the next.

Answer (score 0):

The author is looking for someone who enjoys having adventures and living life to its fullest most of the time, but on a rainy Sunday afternoon is happy to cuddle up on the sofa and watch rubbish on television ("doing nothing" together).